# Swapping an integer with a short using a generic function

Tags: c, generics, endianness, memcpy

Assume I have this generic function that swaps two variables:

```
void swap(void *v1, void *v2, int size){
    char buffer[size];
    memcpy(buffer, v1, size);
    memcpy(v1, v2, size);
    memcpy(v2, buffer, size);
}
```

It works fine, but I was wondering in what cases this might break. One case that comes to mind is when we have two different data types and the size specified is not enough to capture the bigger data. for example:

```
int x = 4444;
short y = 5;
swap(&x, &y, sizeof(short));
```

I'd expect that when I run this it would give an incorrect result, because `memcpy` would work with only 2 bytes (rather than 4) and part of the data would be lost or changed when dealing with `x`.

Surprisingly though, when I run it, it gives the correct answer on both my Windows 7 and Ubuntu operating systems. I know that Ubuntu and Windows differ in endianness but apparently that doesn't affect any of the two systems.

I want to know why the generic function works fine in this case.

Comment: Endianness is determined by the CPU, not the OS.

Comment: You could swap without the temporary using the ^ operator.

Comment: @user3344003: But why on earth would you?

Comment: @Brian I see. I guess I know why the answer is right, then. I'd expect the answer to be incorrect on a Linux system. Actually I am running my Ubuntu on a VM from inside Windows. So that's why I get the same result!

Comment: @Omid you didn't get the point. If you are running on x86 it doesn't matter if it's Linux, Windows or OSX - it's little endian everywhere.

Comment: No I got the point alright. I am using the same machine with two OSes, so the result should be the same. It's a x86-64 by the way but I guess it is little endian too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this fully you have to understand the C standard and the specifics of you machine and compiler. Starting with the C standard, here's some relevant snippets [The standard I'm using is WG14/N1256], summarized a little:

- The object representation for a signed integer consists of value bits,
  padding bits, and a sign bit. [section 6.2.6.2.2].
- These bits are stored in a contiguous sequence of bytes. [section
  6.2.6.1].
- If there's N value bits, they represent powers of two from 2^0 to
  2^{N-1}. [section 6.2.6.2].
- The sign bit can have one of three meanings, one of which is that is
  has value -2^N (two's complement) [section 6.2.6.2.2].

When you copy bytes from a `short` to an `int`, you're copying the value bits, padding bits and the sign bit of the `short` to bits of the `int`, but not necessarily preserving the meaning of the bits. Somewhat surprisingly, the standard allows this except it doesn't guarantee that the `int` you get will be valid if your target implementation has so-called "trap representations" and you're unlucky enough to generate one.

In practice, you've found on your machine and your compiler:

- a `short` is represented by 2 bytes of 8 bits each.

  - The sign bit is bit 7 of the second byte
  - The value bits in ascending order of value are bits 0-7 of byte 0, and bits 0-6 of byte 1.
  - There's no padding bits
- an `int` is represented by 4 bytes of 8 bits each.

  - The sign bit is bit 7 of the fourth byte
  - The value bits in ascending order of value are bits 0-7 of byte 0, 0-7 of byte 1, 0-7 of byte 2, and 0-6 of byte 3.
  - There's no padding bits

You would also find out that both representations use two's complement.

In pictures (where SS is the sign bit, and the numbers N correspond to a bit that has value 2^N):

```
short:
07-06-05-04-03-02-01-00 | SS-14-13-12-11-10-09-08

int:
07-06-05-04-03-02-01-00 | 15-14-13-12-11-10-09-08 | 23-22-21-20-19-18-17-16 | SS-30-29-28-27-26-25-24
```

You can see from this that if you copy the bytes of a `short` to the first two bytes of a zero `int`, you'll get the same value if the sign bit is zero (that is, the number is positive) because the value bits correspond exactly. As a corollary, you can also predict you'll get a different value if you start with a negative-valued `short` since the sign bit of the `short` has value -2^15 but the corresponding bit in the `int` has value 2^15.

The representation you've found on your machine is often summarized as "two's complement, little-endian", but the C standard provides a lot more flexibility in representations than that description suggests (even allowing a byte to have more than 8 bits), which is why portable code usually avoids relying on bit/byte representations of integral types.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out in the comments the systems you are using are typically little-endian (least significant byte in the lowest address).  Given that the memcpy sets the short to the lowest part of the int.

You might enjoy looking at [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for 'generic' ways to do swap operations.